Is it valid to manipulate context before retrieving it inside a custom ContextProvider?
I have a React custom ContextProvider component. Whenever it is called, I need to set a certain ID inside it, which will base all the CRUD. Now, it is something like this:
import React, { Dispatch, PropsWithChildren, SetStateAction, createContext, useContext } from "react";


export type RepositoryContext = {
  dispatchDelete: (id: number) => Promise<void>;
  dispatchEdit: (body: SelfCollection, action: EditionAction) => Promise<void>;
  dispatchCreate: (body: ScoPostBody) => Promise<void>;
  loadList: () => Promise<void>;
  loading: boolean;
  data: RepoEntities[];
  setFetchingId: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number | undefined>>;
};

const RepositoryContext = createContext<RepositoryContext | null>(null);

export const useRepository = (id?: number) => {
  const context = useContext(ScoRepositoryContext); // Here is my doubt
  if (id) context?.setFetchingId(id);
  return context;
};

export const RepositoryProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  // My context logic here...

  const contextContent = {
    dispatchDelete,
    dispatchEdit,
    dispatchCreate,
    loadList,
    loading,
    data,
    setFetchingId,
  };

  return <ScoRepositoryContext.Provider value={contextContent}>{children}</ScoRepositoryContext.Provider>;
}

And then I wrap my consumer's parent like this:
<RepositoryProvider>
  <ConsumerComponent />
</RepositoryProvider>

I know the context component above is absolutely valid if I set the ID in the context consumer afterwards, and export the hook without manipulating it, as follows:
export const useRepository = () => useContext(ScoRepositoryContext);

My doubt is: is it valid React/JSX code if I make the manipulation in the context before returning it? Or am I breaking any rules of hooks?
P.S.: Before someone says "if it works, it is ok", I need to explain: the app is breaking some rule of hooks and returning an error for rendering hooks inside useEffects/useCalbacks/whatever, but the problem is anywhere else, because even with the "usual" approach, returning the context without manipulating it, I also get the error. This question is purely theoretical, moved by sheer curiosity.

Yes you can set the default state of the context before any part of your app uses it. You need pass the props/data into it and simply set it, then export the context provider for use. Example...
export const ReactProvider = ({ user, children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(combined, { user });
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider
            value = {{ state, dispatch }}
            displayName = "My React Context">
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};

Daniel

You blew my mind! Of course! I can pass it as a prop to the provider wrapper itself. Thnx!
